# Elementary matrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am very new to MATLAB, and I am trying to create a numerical scheme to solve a differential equation. However I am having trouble implementing matrices. I was wondering if anyone can help with constructing a following NxN matrix?

[Matrix to be constructed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdUF7.png)

I am sure there is a better way to implement, but the following works

```
N=10
tod=zeros(N)
for k=1:(N-1)
    tod(k, k+1)=-2
end
for k=1:(N-2)
    tod(k, k+2)=1
end
tod_2=zeros(N)
for k=1:(N-1)
    tod_2(k, k+1)=2
end
for k=1:(N-2)
    tod_2(k, k+2)=-1
end
tran=transpose(tod_2)
Final=tran+tod
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use Matlab's [`toeplitz`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toeplitz.html) command. In particular, you could do the following.

```
N = 10;    % example value; must have N >= 3

r = zeros(1,N);
r(2:3) = [-2,1];
c = -r;
R = toeplitz(c,r);
```

Alternatively, you could use the [`diag`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html?searchHighlight=diag&s_tid=srchtitle_diag_1) command. For instance,

```
d = [-2,1];
R = zeros(N);
for i = 1:2
    diag(R,i) = d(i);
    diag(R,-i) = -d(i);
end
```

Comment: That's a very useful command, but it doesn't return the matrix I need. I need 0's on diagonal, 2's on superdiagonal and -2 on subdiagonal!

Comment: @dannyt I had an off by one error; try it now